Airflow next run shows me the wrong date
I have an issue, that next run of the dag is wrong in the web interface (Actually, it is executing on time and works fine). Eventually, my problem is why web interface next run does not show me date I am expecting ? When I am touching the tooltip of the next run, here time is absolutely fine. I am going to attach two screenshots. Screenshot of the next run (Which shows me wrong date) and screenshot of next run with tooltip (Which shows me the correct date). I want to mention one more time, that dags are executed on time. Actually, I want to "fix" web interface next run date.


This is my Python code:
with DAG(
    dag_id='my_dag',
    schedule='5 4 * * *',
    catchup=False,
    default_args={
        'owner': 'user',
        'start_date': pendulum.now(tz='EST5EDT') - pendulum.duration(days=1), # I tried here to set some statis time, Let's say datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1)
    }
) as dag:
    task1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task1',
        python_callable=my_callable_1,
    )
    task2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task2',
        python_callable=my_callable_2,
    )
    task1 >> task2

Any ideas ?

Well, the next DAG run will indeed be the execution for the date 2024-05-27 and is scheduled for 2024-05-28. Nothing's wrong here. Read carefully this page on data-interval
